# django openshift import views error

Tags: django, import, openshift

It's been impossible for me to make work any django "Hello World" example on openshift. I'm just trying to do the most basic example based on urls.py, views.py and wsgi.py.
This is the structure

```
wsgi
-myproject
--myproject
---__init__.py
---settings.py
---urls.py
---views.py
---wsgi.py
```

and urls.py, where is the import views (with # you can see some trials)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
#from . import views
#import views
from myproject import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

The thing is that I can't get out of the "ImportError - cannot import name views" situation. I've read lots of stackoverflow threads, tried lots of answers but nothing.
Istead of importing, if I copy the views.py content into urls.py, it works ok.

Here the wsgi.py content, full of sys.path.append that I added trying to find a solution:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR']))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'myproject'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'myproject'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python3.3/site-packages')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
```

I created this project into the openshift web console, and modified it with liclipse (eclipse pydev).
The thing has to do with openshift, I made some local examples and no problem at all.

PLEASE HELP - I'm really starting to think that openshift doesn't work with django, at least for beginners.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using a relative import since your views is in the same dir as urls:

```
from . import views
```

And maybe read the python docs on how to use absolute/relative imports: https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is the first thing I did. You can see this line with the # in my urls.py. I think I need a simple but truly working example.

Comment: oh sorry that wasn't helpful then. another option is to put it in a string and don't import views like this: openshift example on github: https://github.com/openshift/django-ex/blob/master/project/urls.py

Comment: Yes, thanks, this works. And also works if I simply copy the views.py content into urls.py.
But I will not go too far by this way, I would like to make work a basic import, otherwise I will never be able to use views into a project.

Comment: Well the project dir and app dir(s) should be separate. The project usually contains settings, urls, wsgi etc. urls.py reference the views of your app(s) - in this case django-ex/welcome/views.py. The url function inside urls.py can accept your index function object (as you did above) or a string with its qualified name, so essentially it has the same effect as importing it. I'm not sure I see the limitation you are describing.